# Hollow isosceles triangle # Console

Tags: c#

There are a lot of examples to create a triangle in C# 
but now i need a hollow one here fore there are a lot of examples in C or  C++ but i need one in C# console , can some body give me a few examples

```
     *
   * * *
  * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * * *
```

```
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    for (j = 5 - i; j > 0; j--)
        Console.Write(" ");

    for (j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++)
        Console.Write("*");

    Console.WriteLine();

}
```

```
     *
   *   *
  *     *
 *       *
* * * * * *
```

Comment: The top 2 lines of your triangles are inconsistent. It's like you're missing the second line. Is this intentional? It certainly makes the problem harder.

Comment: Write out a hollow triangle by hand, and for each row count the number of spaces you have to draw between the asterisks. Write this down and study it. You should be able to come up with some relationship between the row number and the number of spaces. Then encode that in an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This Works...But if the value is greater than that s printable on a single line it breaks into next line. The maximum possible value without line break is 40. Till 40 it works well and good in my system. For larger values you have to increase the width of command prompt. It can be done using commands or by changing the width in properties of command prompt.

```
        int i, j,n=5;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            for (j = n - i; j > 0; j--)
                Console.Write(" ");

            for (j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++)
            {
                if (j < 2 * i && j > 0&&i!=(n-1))
                    Console.Write(" ");
                else
                    Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Great. But it would look better if the last line could be written with alternating stars and spaces.

Comment: @Farhan Anam It s working. since screen width of command prompt is fixed it goes to next line for large values. We cannot control it i think so. But for smaller values like 30 it works well.

Comment: Yes of course it's working. who said it's not? I was just saying that it won't work if Line width(actual width) > ConsoleWidth. However there are ways to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    Int32 totalLines = 9;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i <= totalLines; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(Line(i, totalLines));
}

String Line(Int32 i, Int32 totalLines)
{
    Int32 charCount = 2 * totalLines + 1;
    Int32 center = charCount / 2;

    // Last line is filled completely
    if (i == totalLines) return new String(Enumerable.Repeat('*', charCount).ToArray());

    Char[] chars = Enumerable.Repeat(' ', charCount).ToArray();
    chars[center-i] = '*';
    chars[center+i] = '*';
    return new String(chars);
}
```

This will only work with monospace fonts.

Comment: For future reference: string has an overload to duplicate the a char based on a count int. So instead of ``return new String(Enumerable.Repeat('*', charCount).ToArray());`` you could simply write ``new string('*', charCount);`` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx